# Best software (or other) solution for modeling existing complex MySQL schema

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, data-structures, schema

What's a good solution for modeling an existing and very complicated MySQL schema.  Preferably with the following features:

- completely visual
- drill down on click
- shows keys, indexes
- gives sample data per field*

*as fields aren't always intuitively named

Thanks!
Emile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Try [MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/5.2.html)

> MySQL Workbench provides DBAs and developers an integrated tools environment for:
>
> - Database Design & Modeling
> - SQL Development (replacing MySQL Query Browser)
> - Database Administration (replacing MySQL Administrator)

You can also check this interesting post [Top 10 MySQL GUI Tools](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3880961/Top-10-MySQL-GUI-Tools.htm)

Comment: Sandy, thanks for your advice!!  I've heard of MySQL workbench for designing new tables, but just discovered the reverse engineering link, which helps with my "existing" schema needs.